# ATL-based HBO plugin for IE: Missing library on other machines

Tags: windows, plugins, internet-explorer-8, atl, loadlibrary

I'm writing some HBO for Internet Explorer in Visual Studio 2010. On my development machine all works great. To register DLL i use system tool regsvr32 like following.

```
regsvr32 plugin.dll
```

However, when I try to do the same on other machine I get an error message saying that system couldn't load DLL module. I'm pretty sure path to my extension DLL is correct, so I believe that system doesn't meet other dependencies. In VS I build my plugin in "Release" mode, so it should include all necessary things to run somewhere else. I also changed /MD to /MT (friend's advice - sadly it is not working).

I've been searching system event log against additional information but without success. What I have to do then? I mean how to check which libraries should I have on the other machine (or maybe it's obvious - then just tell me the names).

**EDIT**: I found a solution, maybe someone will find it helpful: add "atl.lib" without quotes to Linked additional dependencies in Visual Studio and all should work fine.

Regards

Comment: 1 - Make sure you have sufficient permissions on the other machine. If it's Vista/7 with UAC, you'll have to run regsvr32 as an administrator. 2 - Use Sysinternal's ProcMon to see what files are loaded during the registration. If a file is missing, you'll see it in the log.

Comment: @eran I'm using Windows XP on both machines. With ProcMon I figured out that I need to include atl100.dll file along with my BHO. But there's another problem: Now i get this error message: "plugin.dll is not an executable file and no registration helper is registered for this file type." What the heck? This time ProcMon didn't help much.

Comment: If the problem is indeed solved, you can write the solution as an answer. Then, check the V next to it, so it will show as solved.

Comment: Added solution as an answer (I had to wait for 8 hours to do that). Same with V - I must wait 2 more days to accept my own answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is: add "atl.lib" without quotes to Linked additional dependencies in Visual Studio and all should work fine.